# How to get column value from single active record object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I get Issue object from a table

```
@issue = Issue.where(id: issue_id)
```

So I have the next active record object.

```
ActiveRecord::Relation::WhereClause:0x00007f88ea670f00 @predicates=[#<Arel::Nodes::Equality:0x00007f88ea670fa0 @left=#<struct Arel::Attributes::Attribute relation=#<Arel::Table:0x00007f88ea05fe68 @name="issues", @type_caster=#<ActiveRecord::TypeCaster::Map:0x00007f88ea05fee0 @types=Issue(id: integer, tracker_id: integer, project_id: integer, subject: string, description: text, due_date: date, category_id: integer, status_id: integer, assigned_to_id: integer, priority_id: integer, fixed_version_id: integer, author_id: integer, lock_version: integer, created_on: datetime, updated_on: datetime, start_date: date, done_ratio: integer, estimated_hours: float, parent_id: integer, root_id: integer, lft: integer, rgt: integer, is_private: boolean, closed_on: datetime)>, @table_alias=nil>, name="id">, @right=#<Arel::Nodes::BindParam:0x00007f88ea670fc8 @value=#<ActiveRecord::Relation::QueryAttribute:0x00007f88ea670ff0 @name="id", @value_before_type_cast=1, @type=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter::SQLite3Integer:0x00007f88e6cd3950 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=nil, @range=-9223372036854775808...9223372036854775808>, @original_attribute=nil>>>]>}
```

with `project_id: integer` column, but when I tried to get project_id value - it threw an error

My code:

```
project_id = @issue.project_id
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `project_id' for #<Issue::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fdb03e0e008>
Did you mean?  object_id):
```

Comment: Try `Issue.where(id: issue_id).pluck(:project_id)`. Reason: `where` returns an `Issue::ActiveRecord_Relation` (many objects), `project_id` is meant to be invoked in a single object. `pluck` gets every argument passed corresponding to the table columns and returns them in an array.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks for the note, but already read about pluck and still not understand how to get project_id from object to variable.

Comment: If you need a single record, then you should use find instead of where. Try `Issue.find(issue_id).project_id`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes, that's it, SteveTurczyn already answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@issue = Issue.where(id: issue_id)
```

The above gives you a relation that contains one issue (or no issues if no match is found).

If you want the issue itself, you can do

```
@issue = Issue.where(id: issue_id).take
```

Or more commonly

```
@issue = Issue.find_by(id: issue_id)
```

The above gives you the issue (if found) or nil.

If you know for a fact the issue_id exists, you can do

```
@issue = Issue.find(issue_id)
```

But that will generate a runtime error if the record is not found.

Comment: I'd say `.first` is more idiomatic than `.take`.

Comment: I think `take` is slightly more performant... maybe not in this "retrieve by id" example but certainly in other queries where there are possibly multiple matching records.  David Aldridge covers this here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498255/2516474

Comment: That’s interesting. I didn’t realize Rails would order by primary key by default.